# Minifier js in my browser cause variable already been declared

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I have a little problem with my js file, when I minify my file, and put it online, the browser further minimizes it, for example by replacing the variable names with letters, and I see that one of the variables is replaced by "e", and knowing I'm using an `e.preventDefault ()` in my code, so this causes me the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'e' has already been declared
```

So, I have a two file, number one named: contact_form.js and two: newsletter_form.js

The number one is executed in my home page with form

The number two is executed in all my view pages because the newsletter is a modal that opens from a menu available on all pages.

CODE:
This is my normal code:

```
let contact_email = document.getElementById('email');
let contact_nom = document.getElementById('nom');
let contact_prenom = document.getElementById('prenom');
let contact_message = document.getElementById('message');
let info_contact = document.getElementById('info_contact_bot');
let checkbox_verify = document.getElementById('contact_accepter');
let contact_submit = document.getElementById('submit');

let verifier_contact = false;

contact_email.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    let info_email = document.getElementById('info_email');
    if(confirmEmail(contact_email.value)){
        contact_email.style.border = "solid 2px green";
        verifier_contact = true;
    } else {
        contact_email.style.border = "solid 2px red";
    }
});

contact_submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        if(contact_nom.value.length !== 0 && contact_prenom.value.length !== 0 && contact_email.value.length !== 0 && contact_message.value.length !== 0){
            if(response.length !== 0){
                if(checkbox_verify.checked === true){
                    if(confirmEmail(contact_email.value)){
                        info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color: rgb(1, 196, 1);'>Merci de patienter ...</h5>";
                    } else {
                        info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color:red;'>E-Mail non valide !</h5>";
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }else {
                    info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color:red;'>Vous devez accepter la politique.</h5>";
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }else {
                info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color:red;'>Veuillez cocher le captcha.</h5>";
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        } else {
            info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color:red;'>Veuillez remplir tout les champs !</h5>";
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    setTimeout(function() {
        info_contact.innerHTML = "";
    }, 2000);});
```

And my code in browser becomes:

```
let e=document.getElementById("email"),t=document.getElementById("nom"),n=document.getElementById("prenom"),l=document.getElementById("message")...etc
```

Comment: Browsers don't minify code; they take whatever's given to them by the server. The minification process is causing this problem.

Comment: did you try changing e to event?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is something you have already tried, looking at the function declaration for the click event handler you have used e as the parameter name,

[image: original code snip]

try expanding this to event, as in the below;

```
let contact_email = document.getElementById('email');
let contact_nom = document.getElementById('nom');
let contact_prenom = document.getElementById('prenom');
let contact_message = document.getElementById('message');
let info_contact = document.getElementById('info_contact_bot');
let checkbox_verify = document.getElementById('contact_accepter');
let contact_submit = document.getElementById('submit');

let verifier_contact = false;

contact_email.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    let info_email = document.getElementById('info_email');
    if(confirmEmail(contact_email.value)){
        contact_email.style.border = "solid 2px green";
        verifier_contact = true;
    } else {
        contact_email.style.border = "solid 2px red";
    }
});

contact_submit.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let response = grecaptcha.getResponse();

        if(contact_nom.value.length !== 0 && contact_prenom.value.length !== 0 && contact_email.value.length !== 0 && contact_message.value.length !== 0){
            if(response.length !== 0){
                if(checkbox_verify.checked === true){
                    if(confirmEmail(contact_email.value)){
                        info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color: rgb(1, 196, 1);'>Merci de patienter ...</h5>";
                    } else {
                        info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color:red;'>E-Mail non valide !</h5>";
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }else {
                    info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color:red;'>Vous devez accepter la politique.</h5>";
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }else {
                info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color:red;'>Veuillez cocher le captcha.</h5>";
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        } else {
            info_contact.innerHTML = "<h5 style='color:red;'>Veuillez remplir tout les champs !</h5>";
            event.preventDefault();
        }

    setTimeout(function() {
        info_contact.innerHTML = "";
    }, 2000);});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I try it but nothing, he replace event with : `c.addEventListenner`

---------------------------------- EDIT

I find a solution, is a cloudlfare whoever puts the files in cache, just disable caching cloudlflare.